# Are security questions no longer required for Apple ID account security?

Tags: security, apple-id, accounts, two-factor-authentication

I lost security questions/answers for my old Apple ID, so I can't do many things. Therefore, I registered a new Apple ID account by going to System Preferences → iCloud. I enabled two-factor authentication and provided a trusted phone number. The weird thing in this new account is that it didn't ask me to provide any security questions and answers.

I am afraid the stupid security questions/answers will cause new problems later on in my new account, I accessed the [Manage your Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage) webpage to find a way to provide it. But in the **Security** section of my new account, there are no **Security Questions** setup at all.

I am very confused about Apple ID security. Are security questions required or not? These security questions killed my old account, but no longer exist in my new account.

I just don't get it. Why don't I have them?

Comment: LOL, I have the opposite question.  How do I bypass the security questions?  Pardon, not trying to hijack your valid question, but: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/346719/112208

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accounts with two-factor authentication enabled do not require or use security questions.

[Two-factor authentication for Apple ID - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204915)

> **Do I still need to remember any security questions?**
>
> No. With two-factor authentication, you don't need to remember any security questions. We verify your identity exclusively using your password and verification codes sent to your trusted devices and phone numbers. When you enroll in two-factor authentication, we keep your old security questions on file for two weeks in case you need to return your account to its previous security settings. After that, they're deleted.

If you are enabling two-factor authentication on an existing account, you may need to answer the security questions to complete the process.

> You might be asked to answer your Apple ID security questions.

Comment: It would be very helpful if anyone can change my negative thinking on two factor trap because I just had this happen to me also and the way I feel is Now I have no choice to separate my devices from each other, I now must have 2 devices with me at all times? Now I'm forced to enter my passcodes from my devices. I don't want to provide that information Unless there is more transparency that provides me with a history of exactly what " trusted devices and phone numbers are connected with my Apple ID. Not in the way that would require me to have to stare at the trusted devices window 24/7.

Comment: @Lisa I'd encourage you to take this to [chat] so others can see this discussion and these comments will be cleaned up shortly! That comment would make for a great starting point for conversation.